# GDB/MI access qualifers

Tags: gdb

When using GDB/MI [variable object](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Variable-Objects.html) with with `-var-list-children`, is there a way to turn off the returning of children with`public, private, protected` qualifiers and just return the actual objects with value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way.  This is a longstanding oddity of MI.  There is a bug open for it in gdb bugzilla, IIRC, but as far as I know nobody has ever worked on fixing it.

Comment: Can you link the bug?